# Reproducing figures from 2017 Developer Survey

Tags: support, survey, survey-2017

I'm trying to reproduce some of the analysis from the 2017 survey (ahead of working on the 2018 data when available). Thus far I'm failing even the most basic questions.

Official [data](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/) and [analysis](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stackoverflow.results2017

51392
```

> a total of 51,392 usable responses

So far so good.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stackoverflow.results2017 WHERE Gender != "NA"

35047
```

> [35,990 responses](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#developer-profile-gender)

I've had this problem using the Kaggle hosted dataset and with the CSV imported into a database, so I think the issue is more with my understanding!

Is there another column I need to be checking to get matching numbers?

Comment: Gender doesn't seem all that simple, given that they included a lot of different options. Are you sure you're not just missing categories in your query? Is there another easier query that is failing?

Comment: I also count 35,047 just performing a filter on the csv in a popular spreadsheet application. Was there an option in the survey last year to have your data removed in the public full data set release? It is called `survey_results_public` after all, not just `survey_results`

Comment: If the full data for a given person was removed - it wouldn't show in the grand total (ie the first query). So I don't suspect this is the problem... I'd start with a `select Gender, count(*) from stackoverflow.results2017 group by Gender;` to see what the actual options are.

Comment: @Shadow Well, I've stuck it up at https://pastebin.com/M63AaaJ9, but I don't think it's terribly interesting. After all, I'm just trying to exclude people who didn't answer the question. Undoubtedly the 35047/35990 breaks down across the gender spectrum, but that's not what I'm looking for yet.

Comment: So here's another interesting one: `select COUNT(*) FROM stackoverflow.results2017 WHERE Country = 'United Kingdom'` - this returns `4395`, but the _Employment Status by Geography_ section says 4740 - although the figures for United States and Canada **do match**.
If we are talking about exclusion from the public results, it would be very odd for a bunch of UK developers to exclude themselves and yet zero North Americans.